# Backup Android to NAS with Rsync

Tags: android, ssh, backup, rsync, nas

How to backup an Android device (Not Rooted)  to a NAS with Rsync over SSH ?

Here is a little Howto that can help :

1. Configure Keys
   Either use dropbear both side or create Open ssh keys and convert the private key to dropbear :

> ```
> ssh-keygen -t rsa -f rsync.key
> sudo apt-get install dropbear
> /usr/lib/dropbear/dropbearconvert openssh dropbear rsync.key rsync.key.db
> ```

Copy `rsync.key.pub` to the server `.ssh/authorized.keys`
Copy private key `rsync.key.db`to the Android device (where you want) and the public key to the

2. Install Syncopoli (great opens source software thanks to the author !)

If you are running Android on arm-V7-a, you can download apk here :
https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.amoradi.syncopoli/

If you are running Android on arme-V8-a, you have to clone the git repository git clone https://gitlab.com/fengshaun/syncopoli.git, add the jni sources from the source tarball  on f-droid  and compile an new apk with Android Studio.

3. Configure Suncopoli
   In the parameters change :

   - sever address to your NAS IP
   - protocol to SSH
   - private key to the absolute path to the private key on your Android device (i.e `/storage/emulated/0/data/rsynch.key.db`)

In the Action page, create a task : 
- Local to remote (for backup on NAS)
- set a profile name
- set the source folder to backup (i.e. `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera`)
- set a destination (i.e. `/media/share/camera`)

And run the task .. files should appear on your NAS

Comment: Actually this should be the answer to your own question. And indicate if root is required or not.

Comment: Root not required on the Android device

Comment: You should separate the above text in a question and an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change few things on Debian Buster. First, converting a key was giving me `Error: Unrecognised key type` until I specified PEM format. Also, if passphrase was specified it failed with `Error: Ciphers other than DES-EDE3-CBC not supported`. So correct procedure to create key was:

```
sudo apt-get install dropbear
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -N '' -f rsync.key
/usr/lib/dropbear/dropbearconvert openssh dropbear rsync.key rsync.key.db
```

Also, while this rsync over ssh works just fine in v0.5.2 from `F-Droid.org`, in v0.5.3 the jobs don't even try to connect for some reason, so I had to downgrade for it to work. Funnily, I could upgrade afterwards to v0.5.3 and it continued to work.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trouble I did it! Syncopoli isn't well documented (now) and not very handy (now). So it looks like a bad combination, BUT when it works it do fine, really fast and with a lot less implications than e. g. Syncthing. For other users here my troubles and solutions for Local → Remote (e. g. rsyncing from mobile to your NAS):

1. I'm using the latest version v0.6 of Syncopoli.
2. Establishing rsync (NOT via ssh!) was pretty easy.
3. Tap on your established folder for syncing (not the play button) will showing you the debug screen.
4. But ssh droves me nuts. First of all it looks like Syncopoli accepts RSA Keys only, which you have to convert into the Dropbear format. (The tool dropbearconvert is part of the main package). You have to generate a key pair with openssh, convert the secret key and move them to your phone at any place. The public key (not converted) belongs to your remote ~/.ssh/authorized.keys. (But I'm not sure if this is really necessary.) After that you DON'T need dropbear at all, so you don't have to establish a dropbear server instead you can keep your openssh. (Of course some maschines prefer dropbear due to the smaller size e. g. RasPi, OpenWRT). WITHOUT converting it wont work!
5. I tried an Ed25519 cypher and it wont work, too.
6. When generated the RSA key pair you have to use the **'-m PEM'** as additional flag, which specifies the PEM-format. Otherwise dropbearconvert won't converting your key. That way e. g.

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -o -a 100 -m PEM -f /tmp/android_rsa -N ""

7. When your using a different key type with sshd on your server (e. g. Ed25519) you have to add/uncomment the follwoing line in your */etc/ssh/sshd_config*:

> HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key

Otherwise you getting error like *"no matching algo hostkey"*.

8. The converted and to your phone moved secret key will stay there and potentially readable by other Apps. There is no solution since four years.
9. When you establish your connection the first time and you made everything right it may won't work despite. Have a look in the debug screen it will/should show you something like: *"The device with fingerprint xxx try to access your machine. Do you confirm this fingerprint? (y/n)"* In other words you won't ask interactivly for confirmation. You have to go to your Syncopoli settings, tap on "Private Key File" and there you can confirm (or not). BUT it will show the old md5 format. So you have to convert the fingerprint of your public SERVER key. You should find them here: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub To convert is easy with:

> ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub

10. Now it should really work :)
11. You can add "Additional rsync options" in each profile. This is useful for --exclude. E. g. when you're rsyncing your WhatsApp folder under /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp but wont rsync the stickers and voice notes your can exclude them with:

> --exclude 'WhatsApp Sticker' --exclude 'WhatsApp Voice Notes'

12. 

> --exclude={'WhatsApp Sticker','WhatsApp Voice Notes'}

wont work here.

Enjoy!

Resources:
https://brokkr.net/2020/01/12/using-rsync-on-android-getting-syncopoli-talking-to-the-rsync-daemon/
https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html
https://linux-audit.com/using-ed25519-openssh-keys-instead-of-dsa-rsa-ecdsa/
https://gitlab.com/fengshaun/syncopoli/-/issues/40
https://www.unixtutorial.org/how-to-inspect-ssh-key-fingerprints/
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-exclude-files-and-directories-with-rsync/